# Python 3.9.12 build failed - generate-posix-vars failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

New to python. Trying to install `3.9.12` via pyenv. Getting the following error:

```
pyenv install 3.9.12
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.12.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.12/Python-3.9.12.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.12...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.6.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/dz/3d8j_wx508jgkxqzjrfwhbt40000gp/T/python-build.20230125165700.93087
Results logged to /var/folders/dz/3d8j_wx508jgkxqzjrfwhbt40000gp/T/python-build.20230125165700.93087.log

Last 10 log lines:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/dz/3d8j_wx508jgkxqzjrfwhbt40000gp/T/python-build.20230125165700.93087/Python-3.9.12 ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars ;\
    if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
        echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
        rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
        exit 1 ; \
    fi
dyld[4402]: symbol not found in flat namespace (_libintl_bindtextdomain)
/bin/sh: line 1:  4402 Abort trap: 6           DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/dz/3d8j_wx508jgkxqzjrfwhbt40000gp/T/python-build.20230125165700.93087/Python-3.9.12 ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

I'm on an M1. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Is it an option to install it without using `pyenv`?

Comment: `pyenv` works fine on M1. Which pyenv version? Do you have rosetta enabled and/or mix up libraries for different cpu architectures ?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error trying to install 3.9.16 on an M1 mac. I tried reinstalling `xcode-select` and everything else I could find online. nothing worked. I found this [issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2513) that suggests building with rosetta, but that did not work either.

Edit: I fixed my installation but I am really skeptical it will be useful to anyone else. I had just installed the [FreeSurfer](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/) toolkit for neuroimaging and it turns out that it adds many directories to  `PATH`. Removing the FreeSurfer specific part of `PATH` for the installation resolved the problem.

For example, executing the following in your terminal:

```
$ echo PATH
/Applications/freesurfer/bin:/other/freesurfer/or/fsl/dirs:my/path

$ PATH=my/path:without/freesurfer/tings pyenv install 3.9.16
```

Of course, one would need to replace the PATH before the pyenv command with something relevant to their machine.

The specifics of this solution are unlikely to be useful to many people but maybe other programs also mess with `PATH` significantly and could cause a similar error.