# pyenv versio 3.8.6 failing installing on mac m1 version 12.4

Tags: python, apple-m1, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

i am running into an error, what many people already have faced. The big problem is, no matter what I am trying the installation is showing the same error again and again.

Maybe someone can help me.

```
pyenv install 3.8.6                                   ✔  9423  15:42:52
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.6...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.4 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/n9/9hllxbjs5dg0byfs43j5fbdm0000gn/T/python-build.20230217154339.44173
Results logged to /var/folders/n9/9hllxbjs5dg0byfs43j5fbdm0000gn/T/python-build.20230217154339.44173.log

Last 10 log lines:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/n9/9hllxbjs5dg0byfs43j5fbdm0000gn/T/python-build.20230217154339.44173/Python-3.8.6 ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars ;\
    if test $? -ne 0 ; then \
        echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \
        rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \
        exit 1 ; \
    fi
dyld[55035]: symbol not found in flat namespace '_libintl_bindtextdomain'
/bin/sh: line 1: 55035 Abort trap: 6           DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/n9/9hllxbjs5dg0byfs43j5fbdm0000gn/T/python-build.20230217154339.44173/Python-3.8.6 ./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
generate-posix-vars failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

Comment: Maybe  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75251687/python-3-9-12-build-failed-generate-posix-vars-failed) will help